# Letter head date curve using css

Tags: html, css, 3d

I am not sure about the exact statement I should use but I want a style as in the image below in css: I tried find out but didn't find style like this.

[required style screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBfGH.png)

Comment: You should 1) tell us what you have now, so that we can improve upon it rather than invent a new solution from scratch, and 2) pinpoint which of the many style tricks in the screenshot you mean. The only curves I see are the ones at the very bottom, that are nearly cut off.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the red outline, this whole style is required, I am not sure where to start to get all this. It has curves upper right corner, upper left corner and then curves on bottom as well.

Comment: Can you post your code? nobody code for you. Have you try some search on google? This may help you [ribbon generator](http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple solution. I code it myself:

```
    jsfiddle.net/mnfsgxbh/4/
```